# Extracting html text between elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So, I want to scrape the albums and songs from this site with Beautiful soup. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="listAlbum"> 
    <a id="19215"></a>
    <div class="album">
    "album: "
    <b>"3 Feet High And Rising"</b> == $0
    " (1989)"
  </div> 
  <a href="https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/delasoul/intro.html" target="_blank">Intro
  </a>
  <br> 
  <a href="https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/delasoul/themagicnumber.html" target="_blank">The Magic Number</a>
  <br> 
  <a href="https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/delasoul/changeinspeak.html" target="_blank">Change In Speak</a>
  <br>
```

I want to extract this:
    Album: 3 Feet High And Rising
    Songs: Intro, The Magic Number, Change In Speak

I got the albums with this:

```
allAlbums = soup.findAll('div', {"class" : "album"})
for a in allAlbums:
    albumName = str(a.text)[7:]
    print('album: ' + str(a))
```

I cannot figure out how to get the songs. I've tried these:

```
for s in soup(text = re.compile(r'target="_blank">')):
    print(s.parent)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I hope it will fetch you the required output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content='''
  <div id="listAlbum">
   <a id="19215">
   </a>
   <div class="album">
    "album: "
    <b>
     "3 Feet High And Rising"
    </b>
    == $0
    " (1989)"
   </div>
   <a href="https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/delasoul/intro.html" target="_blank">
    Intro
   </a>
   <br/>
   <a href="https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/delasoul/themagicnumber.html" target="_blank">
    The Magic Number
   </a>
   <br/>
   <a href="https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/delasoul/changeinspeak.html" target="_blank">
    Change In Speak
   </a>
   <br/>
  </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("#listAlbum .album,#listAlbum a"):
    print(item.text.strip())
```

What it produces:

```
"album: "
"3 Feet High And Rising"   
== $0
" (1989)"

Intro
The Magic Number
Change In Speak
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. Couple of questions: 1) how did you know to use BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")? 2) How is soup.select is working here? Is the second argument "#listAlbum a" referring to the "a" in "a href"?

Comment: Your first question is unclear. As for your second question: `soup.select` works like how css selectors does. You might wanna go through this documentation [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). And as for your last question: No this `#` is not referring to a. That is the symbol of `ID` so it is referring to `id="listAlbum"`. Be sure to mark this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
## Prints every album
albums = soup.find_all(class_="album")
for album in albums:
    print(album.get_text())

## Prints every song
songs = soup.find_all('a', target="_blank")
for song in songs:
    print(song.get_text())
```